# ¿Por qué "camello pardal = jirafa"?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, animales, colores

En la entrada de [camello](https://dle.rae.es/camello?) del Diccionario de la Lengua aparece

> **camello pardal**

1. m. desus. jirafa.

Por otro lado, en la entada [pardal](https://dle.rae.es/pardal?) aparece:

> 1. adj. desus. Dicho de una persona: Aldeana; por vestir los aldeanos habitualmente de pardo.
> 2. m. leopardo.
> 3. m. gorrión (‖ pájaro muy abundante en España).
> 4. m. pardillo (‖ ave).
> 5. m. Acónito o anapelo.
> 6. m. coloq. Hombre bellaco, astuto.
> 7. m. desus. **camello pardal.**

De hecho, la primera vez que aparece **jirafa** en el Diccionario de la Lengua es en la edición de 1843, y es un lacónico:

> JIRAFA. f. Camello pardal

¿De dónde viene esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia entry for giraffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe#Etymology)

> Camelopard" /kəˈmɛləˌpɑːrd/ is an archaic English name for the giraffe; it derives from the Ancient Greek καμηλοπάρδαλις (kamēlopárdalis), from κάμηλος (kámēlos), "camel", and πάρδαλις (párdalis), "leopard", referring to its camel-like shape and leopard-like colouration.[6][7]

Thanks to the OP for pointing out that the Spanish entry does include this but not in the section on etymology (where I had originally looked).

> El nombre común «jirafa» y primer término del nombre binominal Giraffa proviene del árabe الزرافة (ziraafa o zurapha), que significa «alta». El segundo término que da nombre a la especie camelopardalis proviene del griego καμηλοπάρδαλη camelopardale y del latín camelopardalis, que significa «camello leopardo».